# Storing 3 values for all 20 elements in an array

Tags: c#

What would be the best way to have 3 values stored for every element in a 20 element sized array? E.g. An array of 20 people, which can store their name, address and phone number.

Would it be along the lines of

```
int[][] myArray = new int[20][3];
```

or something similar?

Thanks

Comment: Use list of  class

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It should be rather a [List](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=VS.110).aspx) of class objects:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string SecondName { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }
}

 List<Person> personList = new List<Person>();
 personList.Add(new Person()
 {
      Name = "Sample",
      SecondName = "S",
      Street = "4825235186"
 });
```

Now you can have more dynamic way of having different count of persons in list. Not a static number. Doing it this style will be much more elastic, because you can add new fields to class and access fields by `list[i].Name` instead of `array[i][1]`